# What is the purpose of "{0, -7}" during string interpolation in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I've seen this syntax in other's code and was just wondering what its outputting. For instance,

```
string foo = "Hello World";
string bar = String.Format("{0, -7}", foo); 
Console.WriteLine(bar);
```

I've experimented with different inputs and have come up with same outputs so not really sure what's going on. Anyone care to enlighten?

Comment: If I remember correctly it adds spacing? At any rate there are options that add spacing. Perhaps it is trailing spacing and so you aren't seeing the difference?

Comment: Such construction reserves fixed spaces number for the data formatted (in your case, it is 7 spaces), and aligns the data **left** (if you specify not -7 but 7 it aligns **right**). If your data is longer than 7 places, an overflow will occur, so in this case you'll have to truncate the data by `.Substring` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used to have Left padding ...

Did you know you need to have 30 chars to post an answer?

This:

```
string test = "test";
Console.Out.WriteLine(test);
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, 10} 10 pad", test));
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -10} -10 pad", test));
```

will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A negative number adds padding to the left, whereas a positive number adds padding to the right.  As the string `Hello World` is longer than the padding you've provided, you don't see the result.  Try these instead:

```
string foo = "Hello";
string bar = String.Format("{0, 7}", foo);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", bar); 

bar = String.Format("{0, -7}", foo);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", bar);
```

Adding the quotes around `bar` makes it easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Format Item Syntax**
>   Each format item takes the following form and consists of the following components:
>   **{ index[,alignment][:formatString]}**
>   The matching braces ("{" and "}") are required.
>
> **Alignment Component**
>   The optional alignment component is a signed integer indicating the preferred formatted field width. If the value of alignment is less than the length of the formatted string, alignment is ignored and the length of the formatted string is used as the field width. The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if alignment is positive and left-aligned if alignment is negative. If padding is necessary, white space is used. The comma is required if alignment is specified.